# Cron is running but php-cli inside it doesn't

Tags: php, cron

I've a peculiar situation I cannot get to the bottom of it.

I've cron.php that runs every 15 minutes. It must execute following code:

```
exec("php gmail-smtp.php >> basic-email-template/debug-mailer.log &");
```

All the other parts of the cron work fine, like `require "config.php";` which makes me think relative urls work fine inside cron. But relative url inside exec() could be a problem, unfortunately I don't see anything in the logs, and I don't see anything inside my own debug-mailer.log

Any thoughts?

I tried it both on my local dev mac, and remote ubuntu server. Result is same, ergo no result.

Cron is run like this:

```
*/5 * * * * php /Library/WebServer/Documents/favwords/lib/cron.php
```

Comment: cron jobs are executed with their working directory set to the controlling account's home directory. If running gmail-smtp from the cli in that home directory works, then there's no reason it shouldn't run as well in cron.

Comment: @MarcB nope gmail-smtp is inside /var/www/project/ Should I post full cron file?

Comment: if the cron job is running in (say) /home/foo, then you'd need `exec('php /var/www/project/gmail-smtp' .... )`

Comment: @MarcB why am I not seeing php-cli logs ? or better where do I see them?

Comment: @MarcB btw, I've put full url path for both log file and gmail.php and nothing.

Comment: cron also tends to email any output from the job to the owner of the job. no idea if that's the case with mac cron, but might be worth checking.

Comment: @MarcB they say silent cron is succesful cron, I don't receive any mail on either ubuntu or mac.

Comment: not really. `/job_that_fails 2>&1 > /dev/null` would also be a silent job, but fails regardless.

Comment: Well I'm not redirecting output to null so :) I usually receive mail on server when cron fails, easy to check with mailx under root account. But I'm at loss in this case. Totally silent and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like current working directory is not valid. You can check it out by using `getcwd()` function inside your cron.php script. If it runs at all. After verifing it, use `chdir()` function to change current working directory to valid one - the one where `gmail-smtp.php` is. Or simply use full paths, not relative ones.

Comment: Does cron.php know where it is located when it is run via cron? Since gmail-smtp is relative to cron.php I can use that.

Comment: cron uses the home directory of the account it's running the job as. So if it's running as a job of user `foo`, it'll start in `foo`'s home directory.

Comment: Use `$my_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` to obtain currntly running script path. It's not the same as current working directory in your case.

Comment: How come require "config.php"; this works? This is what got me confused.

Comment: require path is relative to a path of file from which it was called, but current working directory may be different and surely is in your case.

Comment: It was the path issue in the end.